# jQuery validation plugin: accept only alphabetical characters?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'd like to use jQuery's validation plugin to validate a field that only accepts alphabetical characters, but there doesn't seem to be a defined rule for it. I've searched google but I've found nothing useful.

Any ideas?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If you include the additional methods file, here's the current file for 1.7: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js

You can use the `lettersonly` rule :)  The additional methods are part of the zip you download, you can always find the latest [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Here's an example:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    myField: { lettersonly: true }
  }
});
```

It's worth noting, each additional method is independent, you can include that specific one, just place this before your `.validate()` call:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters only please");
```

Comment: ^[A-Za-z]+$ to also accept capital letters, or set value to lower case with toLowerCase() function.

Comment: Note that `lettersonly` will consider special characters invalid, for example, names like `José` or `André` will be invalid.

Answer (score 16):

Be careful,

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) 
{
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z," "]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters and spaces only please");
```

[a-z, " "] by adding the comma and quotation marks, you are allowing spaces, commas and quotation marks into the input box.

For spaces + text, just do this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) 
{
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters and spaces only please");
```

[a-z ] this allows spaces aswell as text only.

............................................................................

also the message "Letters and spaces only please" is not required, if you already have a message in messages:

```
messages:{
        firstname:{
        required: "Enter your first name",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least (2) characters"),
        maxlength:jQuery.format("First name too long more than (80) characters"),
        lettersonly:jQuery.format("letters only mate")
        },
```

Adam

Answer (score 5):

Both Nick and Adam's answers work really well.

I'd like to add a note if you want to allow latin characters like `á` and `ç` as I wanted to do:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('lettersonly', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z áãâäàéêëèíîïìóõôöòúûüùçñ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters and spaces only please");
```

Comment: Thanks! but u also forgot ñ hehe :)

Comment: Thanks, @Andres! I just updated my answer and added `ñ`

Comment: Great, though some extra letter could be here just in case: å  ø 
And probably a dash / hyphen should be added as escaped `\-`

Answer (score 4):

Just a small addition to Nick's answer (which works great !) :

If you want to allow spaces in between letters, for example , 
you may restrict to enter only letters in full name, but it should allow space as well - just list the space as below with a comma. And in the same way if you need to allow any other specific character:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) 
{
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z," "]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters and spaces only please");
```

Answer (score 3):

to allow letters ans spaces

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Only alphabetical characters");

$('#yourform').validate({
        rules: {
            name_field: {
                lettersonly: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.AlphabetsOnly').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/);
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping in a function:

```
   $(function(){
   jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersOnly", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/i.test(value);
   }, "Please enter letters only.");
```

});