# jQuery validation plugin - "lettersonly" function

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, letters

i am quite new to jQuery and I'm trying to use the lettersonly function for my signup form. I have looked at **[this question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794162/jquery-validation-plugin-accept-only-alphabetical-characters)** but implementing it didn't seem to work for me.

Here's my code:

```
            <form class="kennzeichen-input-big" action="step1.php">
                <input type="text" name="kuerzel" id="kuerzel" style="font-size:50px;" maxlength="3" required> 
                <input type="submit" value="Zur Reservierung" class="btn signup" style="width:auto; margin-top:15px; margin-left:20px;">


</form>

    <script>
        $("form").validate(
        { rules: { ('#kuerzel'): { lettersonly: true } } }
        );
    </script>
```

I assume the problem is with the "`myField`" tag? I have tried several things, but didnt get it to work. I did include the additional functions, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're missing is that the field must be referenced by it's **name** attribute in the Validate call.

```
    $("form").validate(
    { rules: { ('#kuerzel'): { lettersonly: true } } }
    );
```

Becomes:

```
    $("form").validate(
    { rules: { kuerzel: { lettersonly: true } } }
    );
```

That's it, assuming you aren't seeing any other errors on the page...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried that and it didn't help. I'm not seeing any other issues and the general "required" comment works.

Comment: Hard to tell from the information given what's actually wrong then, because it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/cc9yxt2a/

Comment: Maybe there are other forms on the page?  And the validate rules are being attached to the wrong one?

Comment: Only a single form on the page, I'm pretty much stumped at this point, but i will continue trying. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: What jQuery script do you use? Additional methoesd isnt working: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js Im having a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384682/using-only-one-jquery-validation-script-that-also-supports-addmethod. my sample project  https://information-contact.000webhostapp.com/