# Validate first 4 characters using jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, plugins

I don't know if this question has already been answer before. 
What I'm trying to do is validate an input text, but i need the length to be less than 10 characters and I need the 4 first characters to be Letters only and the rest only Numbers

how can i achieve this using the jQuery Validation Plugin?,  i chose to use this plugin because it seems to be the easiest way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery validation plugin: accept only alphabetical characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794162/jquery-validation-plugin-accept-only-alphabetical-characters)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    myField: { lettersonly: true }
  }
});
```

To ensure the max lenth, use the `maxlengh` attribute.

If you nee to only check the first 4 characters for alpha ... roll your own.

Comment: doesn't solve problem of validating first 4 characters

Comment: Hence why I said "roll your own" ... the library doesn't support "first four characters".

Comment: So how does this answer help then when it doesn't do what is asked?

Comment: It gets them started on alpha-only.  Then the callback to handle the "first four".

Comment: Considering that  `lettersonly` is a custom method don't see how this helps at all  and implies something that doesn't exist